# Is there a "Take Selector" in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere

Does Premiere have an equivalent to DaVinci Resolve's "Take Selector, or FCPX's "Auditions?"  If so, what's it called?  If not, are there any workarounds to quickly audition alternate takes on a PP timeline and have all of the other clips ripple responsively?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a smarter method, but here's what I did:

When structuring your project, I recommend you use the bins in Premiere frequently. For example, as a structure, you could have:

---

- Footage

  - psd
  - cam1

    - A001
    - A002
    - A003
    - A004

      - A1
      - A2
      - A2b
      - A3
      - B2

        - T1

          - ffsa7b2t1.mov
        - T2

          - ffsa7b2t2.mov
        - T3

          - ffsa7b2t3.mov
        - T4

          - ffsa7b2t4.mov
      - B3
      - A005
  - cam2
  - gopro
- Solids
- sequences

---

Using this structure of something similar might assure that you exchange or look at different takes without any hassle.